# Anti-spam software for Cent OS 4.8 w/ cPanel

Tags: spam-filter, spam

My company has a dedicated server running CENTOS Enterprise 4.8 with cPanel. We host our own websites as well as about three dozen client websites. We recently migrated our clients over from a Rackspace email solution and many of our clients are complaining that  they are getting a lot more spam now. We do have SpamAssassin enabled and set to be very aggressive (2 or 3) but spam still seems to be an issue.

Any recommendations for server side spam filtering software? Ideally it would complement SpamAssassin but if it is robust in-and-of itself a SpamAssassin replacement would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [MailScanner](http://mailscanner.info/).

It's a significant improvement from SpamAssassin alone, and can provide anti-virus protection as well.  I've used it for 5+ years. Recently, we upgraded to a cluster of hardware-based anti-spam/anti-virus scanners.